# How to sort a field in the window for the top N values and perform aggregate calculations for the corresponding field in DolphinDB?

Tags: quote, sliding-window, dolphindb

My question is about calculating the quote data in DolphinDB. The table contains four columns (ticker, date, close and volume) and is grouped by ticker and sorted by date. I want to do a window calculation and assume the window size to be 20. My purpose is to sort the data in volume column in a window and take the top five volume records to calculate the average of the corresponding values of close. What is the most efficient way to calculate it in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no efficient algorithm for this case, but you can use the function [moving](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/TemplateFunctions/moving.html) together with user-defined functions to obtain the desired result. In the future, DolphinDB will develop functions based on the scenario.

Use a single line of code in version 1.30.15 and above to perform the calculation:

```
//suppose t is a four-column table
t = table(take(`IBM, 100) as code, 2020.01.01 + 1..100 as date, rand(100,100) + 20 as volume, rand(10,100) + 100.0 as close)
```

user-defined [anonymous aggregate function](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/AnonymousFunction.html) is supported in function `moving`

```
select code, date, moving(defg(vol, close){return close[isort(vol, false).subarray(0:min(5,close.size()))].avg()}, (volume, close), 20) from t context by code
```